# How to return a hash containing an array of file names for each owner name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a hash named **"files"** as following :

```
files = {
       'file1.txt' => 'John',
       'file2.rb'  => 'Andrew',
       'file3.txt' => 'John'
}
```

Expected result:

A method that takes this hash as argument and return the hash containing the array of files for 
respective owner. For e.g

```
{
  'John'   =>  ['file1.txt','file3.txt'],
  'Andrew' =>  ['file2.rb']
}
```

Comment: This is a pure-Ruby question so you shouldn't have a Rail's tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you want to iterate over the file hash and for each key value pair you need to check if it already exists in your new hash, then you just want to add the file name to the array or you create a new key value pair.

```
def change_hash(file_hash)
  new_hash = {}
  file_hash.each do |file_name, person|
    if new_hash[person]
      new_hash[person] << file_name
    else
      new_hash[person] = [file_name]
    end
  end
  new_hash
end
```

If you struggle with this, you want to look on how you can manipulate hashes (and arrays) in Ruby. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: You can replace `each` with `each_with_object` and use a temporal hash object.

Comment: To take @Sebastian's suggestion one step further, `def change_hash(files); files.each_with_object({}) { |(file_name, person),new_hash|; (new_hash[person] ||= []) << file_name }; end`. `new_hash[person] ||= []` expands to `new_hash[person] = new_hash[person] || []`. If `new_hash` has no key `person`,  `new_hash[person]` on the right equals `nil`, so `new_hash[person]` is set equal to `[]` before `new_hash[person] << file_name` is executed.

Comment: Even if I used the `each_with_object` approach I didn't shorten it to `(new_hash[person] ||= [])`, kept using the `hash[value] =` way. Thanks for that @CarySwoveland ;)

Comment: There is many ways to refactor this answer, however judging from the question I wanted to go with an easy to read solution! :) Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

```
files.
  group_by(&:last). # {"John"=>[["file1.txt", "John"], ["file3.txt", "John"]], "Andrew"=>[["file2.rb", "Andrew"]]}
  transform_values { |v| v.map(&:first) } # {"John"=>["file1.txt", "file3.txt"], "Andrew"=>["file2.rb"]}
```

Comment: You could write `group_by(&:last)`.